# Facebook Connect implementation for Nokia SDK 1.1

Tags: java, facebook, nokia, nokia-s40

I'm trying to implement a facebook app for Nokia (specifically the Asha Models)

I don't see any libraries or reference on how to implement FBConnect using J2ME or the Nokia SDK.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this Facebook API for Java ME? http://j2megroup.blogspot.com.br/search/label/facebook%20api%20me